# SQLAlchemy: What is the best way to validate a model before inserting or updating

Tags: python, database, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to validate a SQLAlchemy model before it is inserted or updated, e.g

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    foo = db.Column(db.String(255))
    bar = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

I've tried a few approaches, but none seem to work. One possibility was to listen to `before_insert` and `before_update` events, e.g

```
@event.listens_for(MyModel, 'before_insert')
@event.listens_for(MyModel, 'before_update')
def validate_my_model(mapper, connection, model):
    if not is_valid(model):
        raise Exception("the model isn't valid")
```

This works okay, but in tests I get this error unless I roll back the session.

```
This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback()
```

I could call `session.rollback()` in the tests, but I that seems incorrect, since the test is just issuing PUT/POST requests and shouldn't really know anything about the session or any SQLAlchemy internals.

Another option was to listen to `init` events, instead of `before_insert` and `before_update`, but that doesn't handle the update case.

I also tried using the `@validates`, e.g

```
@validates('foo', 'bar')
def validate(self, key, val):
    ...
```

However, the validation relies on both properties, while the `validate` method is called individually for each property. This means that if I try to set both `foo` and `bar` on the model, it attempts to validate the intermediate state where one property has been set but the other hasn't.

Answer (score 0):

try `flask-marshmallow` and marshmallow_sqlalchemy, it is based on `marshmallow` validation package.
it allows you to validate based on your database model.
create a schema file

```
import MyModel
import db
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyAutoSchema

class MyModelSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        sqla_session = Session
        load_instance = True
        model = MyModel
```

adding `model` inside the `Meta` class will help to validate based on the model  and `load_instance` will let us load the object inside the API as a model instance

```
from schemas import MyModelSchema

model_schema = MyModelSchema()

# API post route
def post(self):
    model_json = request.get_json()
    model = model_schema.load(model_json)

    db.session(model)
    db.session.commit() 

    return {"message": "model created"}, 201
```

last to user marshmallow inside flask app and to return a validation error message if the body sent not validated, inside application root file add

```
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from marshmallow import ValidationError

# marshmallow config
ma = Marshmallow(app)

# marshamallow global exception handler
@app.errorhandler(ValidationError)
def handle_marshmallow_validation(err):
    return jsonify(err.messages), 400
```

I hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the provided validation decorator. See: [`sqlalchemy.orm.validates`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapped_attributes.html#simple-validators)

Example:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates

class MyModel(...):
    
    # ...

    status = db.Column(db.String)

    # ...

    @validates("status")
    def validate_status(self, k, status):
        if status.upper() not in ["PENDING", "APPROVED", "DENIED"]:
            raise ValueError("OOPS, invalid status.")
        return status
```

Comment: `@validates` work well, but it only gets called when setting a property, not when inserting/updating a row, which the question mentions. It would be great if someone could add an answer to that!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SQLModel](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/), that allow you to declare a class which inherit from SQLModel.

```py
class Hero(SQLModel, talbe=):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str
    secret_name: str
    age: Optional[int] = None
```

This is class map `pydantic` fields to `sqlalchemy` Columns.

Instantiate a wrong object will raise a `ValidationError`

Refer to [Pydantic documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/) to check how works validation/validators